# How do I order my months (Jan through Dec) in this plot in R? Transforming months to factor gives me thousands of NA

Tags: r

I feel like I've tried about everything...If I transform the months into factors, I get 16 thousand NA's. As my code is I get the plot to come out, but with the months out of order.

I got the original code here: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/283-the-hourly-heatmap.html

I've edited it to fit my data, but my months come out out of order.

My months are numbers in the csv file (int in r), then changing them to abbreviations makes them characters.

```
SoilT.data<-read.csv(file="Transect 1 Soil Temp RStudio Number month.csv")

library(ggplot2)

library(dplyr)
library(viridis)
library(ggExtra)

library(lubridate)
df <-SoilT.data %>% select(Lower.Panel,Day,Hourly,Month,Year)


df <- transform(df, MonthAbb = month.abb[Month])

 

Panel.Area <-unique(df$Lower.Panel)

p <-ggplot(df,aes(Day,Hourly,fill=Lower.Panel))+geom_tile(color= "white",size=0.1)+scale_fill_viridis(name="Hrly Temps",option ="C")


p <-p + facet_grid(Year~MonthAbb)

p <-p + scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = unique(df$Hourly))

p <-p + scale_x_continuous(breaks =c(1,10,20,31))


p <-p + labs(title= paste("Hourly Temperature - Lower Panel",Panel.Area),x="Day", y="Hourly")


p <-p + theme(legend.position = "bottom")+theme(plot.title=element_text(size =14))+theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=6)) +theme(strip.background =element_rect(colour="white"))+theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0))+theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=7))+theme(legend.title=element_text(size=8))+theme(legend.text=element_text(size=6))+removeGrid()

p
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUDFS.jpg)

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` Is this line `df <- transform(df, MonthAbb = month.abb[Month])` causing trouble.  Then, you may need to check the `str(df)` to find the class of `Month`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have constructed  MonthAbb as a factor. That way you could have specified the ordering of the levels attribute which most plotting functions will honor when it comes time for plotting.

```
 df <- transform(df, MonthAbb = factor(month.abb[Month], month.abb(1:12))
```

Factor vectors are actually integers which plotting functions use as indices into the attribute specified at ttime of creation (or the default which was what was being used by your heatmapping function).